# Many to many relation no saved

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I try without success to save a many to many relation.

In my lodger class

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = "lodger")
private List<Contact> contactList;
```

In my contact class

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "lodger_contact", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "lodger_id"))
private List<Lodger> lodger;
```

How i save the relation

```
public void associateDissociateLodgerAndContact(Long lodgerId, List<Long> contactIdToDissociates, List<Long> contactIdToAssociates) {
    Lodger lodger = lodgerRepository.findOne(lodgerId);

    List<Contact> contactList;

    if (lodger.getContactList() == null) {
        lodger.setContactList(new ArrayList<>());
        contactList = lodger.getContactList();
    } else {
        contactList = lodger.getContactList();
    }

    if (contactIdToDissociates != null) {

        for (Iterator<Contact> iterator = contactList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Contact contact = iterator.next();

            for (Long contactId : contactIdToDissociates) {
                if (contact.getContactId().longValue() == contactId.longValue()) {
                    iterator.remove();
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    List<Contact> contactToAssign = contactRepository.findAll(contactIdToAssociates);

    lodger.getContactList().addAll(contactToAssign);
    lodgerRepository.save(lodger);
}
```

Before I do the save, I try to add 2 contact to lodger and remove one. Just before the save, i see there are 2 element in getContactList.

When I do the save, no query is done.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is bi-directional relationship, you should link/unlink both sides of the relationship. You are only updating the relationship from one side - from the `Lodger` side.

Comment: I think in a bidirectional many-to-many association one side must be master and is used to persist changes to the underlying join table. But we have to maintain the bidirectional association yourself

Comment: That is correct. So that means, for every contact object in you should do this `contact.getLodger().add(lodger)` - to associate or `contact.getLodger().remove(lodger)` - to disassociate. I don't see that in your code.

Comment: seem to work, will check if i have same problem elsewhere.